# How to change the e-mail output of a Entity type field in a webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a content type **Agenda**. In this content type I can create paragaphs of the type **Date**. This paragraph has a field **date** and a field **location**.

Now people can attend to **agenda** items by submitting a webform (using the webform module).

In this webform use a Entity type field together with views to make a reference to **date** paragraphs. This reference works perfectly and creates a select with options showing the name of the name together with date and location. But in the e-mail confirmation I don't see the paragraph fields. Only the name of the node. I want to be able to manage how the output looks in the email confirmations.

At the moment I use `[webform_submission:values:agenda]` to get the value from the submission.

The way it looks now is:
`Node:title > Content type [NID]`  But I want to be able to see something like:
`Node:title | Paragraph:Date | Paragraph Location`

How or where can I change this output?

Answer (score 0):

Because I was in quite a hurry, I ended up creating hidden fields in my form for **date** and **location**. Using javascript I fetch the information from the Select field and add them to these hidden field. This way this information is send with the submission.

Not the prettiest way to do it but it works.